# Sash window meeting rails not even

Tags: windows

I'm in the process of refurbing our sash windows. The top and bottom sashes of most of the windows in the house are out of alignment. Photo attached.

There's a 1 inch overlap of the meeting rails. This makes locking the windows and fitting draught proofing difficult.

Were the windows built like this for a reason or is there some movement in the windows causing this?

Should I leave this as is when refurbing the windows or remove some of the frame from the top and bottom sashes to they are flush?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First it looks like the windows are put in reversed. The glazing putty, the angled places around the windows, have always faced out on old windows. What is now the outside should have a profile something like this

[image]

Although while looking for this image, I did find profiles that match what you have there too.

If they are reversed, the angled bottom will keep the window higher in the opening so the middle does not line up. If there is weatherstripping, the groove will not line up. If they are not reversed, and there is weatherstripping around the perimeter, there may be numerous coats of paint on the top and bottom, so the edge does not fit into its corresponding groove anymore, or the metal is bent so it doesn't fit either. More pictures of the frame conditions would help confirm this.

Comment: I think this is my all time favorite question.

Comment: +1 for noticing the sashes are reversed.

Answer (score 0):

These appear to be single or double hung windows, they were intended to be this way for operational use.

Answer (score 0):

On double hung sash windows the top sash should also move up and down.  However it is very common for the top sash to become painted shut and therefore inoperable.  The first culprit is to check that the top sash has not become painted shut whilst not sitting tight to the box frame head (I suspect this is the problem here).  The next culprits are failed mortise and tenon joints, allowing either the top or bottom rail to drop a little.  Remember when the window was first made the meeting rails were level, so on that basis you can use the sashes vertical side stiles to find the problem.  The stiles do not get longer so it must be a gap at the head or a horizontal rail that has dropped.

These sashes do not appear to be fitted inside out but instead are simply chamfered profiles instead of the more common ovolo or lambs tongue. The glass is still sitting to the outside of the sash, with putty on the outside face.